# When is tripe safe to eat?

Tags: nethack

I've recently got my hands on a few tripe rations. I've been told by a few friends that it's a good food source in the early game. Of course, I eat some and promptly begin vomiting. I know that you can polymorph the ration or yourself to make it safe to eat, but I don't really want to waste charges on such a menial thing. So, my question is, when is tripe safe to eat, and/or how can you make it safe without polymorphing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tripe rations, like food rations and several other types of food items, is generally safe to eat. More specifically, *when you eat it* the game rolls to see if the food is rotten. Cursed food is generally more likely to be rotten.

Unless you are an orc or canine, tripe has a higher than normal chance of causing nausea, at 50%.

Basically, there is no specific time or time frame when tripe rations are more or less safe to eat.

More information can be found on the wiki pages for [food](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Food) and [tripe](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Tripe).

Comment: Alright, so I just found some uncursed tripe rations from the local store. I ate some, and now I'm vomiting again. Is this because it was rotten, or is it something else?

Comment: It looks like tripe is more likely than other food to cause nausea than other foods. I edited my answer.

Comment: Considering what it is and how many people get queasy at the thought of eating it IRL, it doesn't surprise me that it makes people you force to eat it in game vomit.

Comment: If you have any other source of food, tripe is worth saving because you can feed it to dogs to make them tame and turn them into a pet. Useful if you lose your pet early on and need a replacement.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: Actually, (almost) any other food works just as well for taming pets. The main reason to save tripe (and *not* feed it to pets) is that keeping a tripe ration in your inventory will make cats and dogs follow you more closely than usual (because it smells delicious to them, obviously). Apples and carrots will do the same for horses.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Is that so? I did not realise any of that, silly me. Thanks!